# Contar valores por columnas

Tags: r, tidyverse

Tengo un df del tipo:

```
caso   prueba1   prueba2 
c1   150   pos
c1   pos   124
c1   neg   pos
c2   147   neg
c2   135   neg
c2   neg   pos
```

Necesito contar, en R, todos los "pos" y "neg" de cada columna y agruparlos por la variable "caso", y que me quede algo así:

```
caso   prueba1   prueba2 
c1   2   2
c2   1   3
```

Cómo puedo hacerlo?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con `tidyverse` puedes agrupar y sumarizar los valores que sean `neg` y `pos`

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  group_by(caso) %>% 
  summarise(prueba1 = sum(prueba1 %in% c("pos", "neg")),
            prueba2 = sum(prueba2 %in% c("pos", "neg"))            
            )

# A tibble: 2 × 3
  caso  prueba1 prueba2
  <chr>   <int>   <int>
1 c1          2       2
2 c2          1       3
```

Si la cantidad de variables es grande para escribirlas una por una puedes usar `across()` junto con las variadas formas de seleccionar un conjunto de variables, en este caso podemos seleccionar un rango: `columna1:columnaN`

```
data %>% 
  group_by(caso) %>% 
  summarise(across(prueba1:prueba2, ~ sum(.x %in% c("pos", "neg"))))
```

Comment: Gracias, Patricio Moracho. Solo una cosa más. Si en vez de 2 pruebas tengo 250, cómo introduzco eso dentro de summarise sin tener que copiar las 250 variables de prueba? Gracias.

Comment: Verifica mi última edición. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias! Me ha funcionado.